# Adding if condition into get-mailbox command

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

I have a PowerShell script to show which mailboxes do not have the Exchange Retention Policy applied. The script works well, but I cannot figure out how to add an `if` condition that if all mailboxes do have the Retention Policy applied, then the following statement "Master Policy applied to all Mailboxes" is added to the text file.

```
Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "Users*" -ResultSize Unlimited -filter {RetentionPolicy -eq $null} |
  where {$_.RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'UserMailbox'} |
  select Alias > c:\retention.txt
```

Comment: you should apply a code style to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect the results of `Get-Mailbox` in a variable:

```
$mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "Users*" -ResultSize Unlimited `
               -Filter {RetentionPolicy -eq $null} |
               ? {$_.RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'UserMailbox'} | select Alias
```

then check if the result is `$null` (no matches found) and create the output accordingly:

```
$outfile = 'C:\retention.txt'
if ($mailboxes -ne $null) {
  $mailboxes > $outfile
} else {
  'Master Policy applied to all Mailboxes' > $outfile
}
```

Replace `>` with `>>` if you want to append to the file.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I understand the logic but I cant seem to get around the error "a positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument $null."

Comment: Disregard. I got it to work. I had an extra ' in the script. Thank you for your help.